# Why wont console print values of i under 2 in FOR loop if it can print values over 2?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Basically what my title says. Here's a piece of code

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 2; i--) {
system.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

this prints all values until 2, hence suggesting that starting from 9 and provided it doesn't go lower than 2, i should be printed. which it does.

now this one doesn't

```
for (int i = 9; i <= 2; i--) {
system.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

what i figure is it should count down to 2 without printing anything, then print 2 and 1, since the criteria is for all values equal or under 2, print i. However nothing shows on the console.

my understanding of the FOR loop might be wrong and i'm really trying to perfect my knowledge of basic concepts so id appreciate your help.

Comment: Your condition will fail on first iteration itself because i=9 is not less then 2. so the loop will terminate.

Comment: `system.out.print` does not compile. Variable `k` is printed while loop variable is `i`. Does this code work as expected at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept is : 
    first loop => i=9, check if 9 >=2 = true   , print 9 , i = i - 1
    second loop => i=8, check if 8 >=2  = true  , print 8 , i = i - 1
    .
    .
    .
    last loop=> i=1, check if 1 >=2  = false , end

in your second example 
   first loop => i=9, check if 9 <=2 = false  ,  end

Hope i help you understand the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Loop is only executed if the condition is true. If it is false, then loop will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to count down from 9 and only print 2 and 1, you'd have to write something like this:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 1; --i) {
    if (i <= 2) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Of course, if all you wanted was to print 2 and 1, you'd normally just write:

```
for (int i = 2; i >= 2; --i) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

You wouldn't typically start the count at 9 unless you wanted to do something with the numbers 9 to 3 (other than ignore them, that is) as well as 2 and 1:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 1; --i) {
    if (i <= 2) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("We're not going to print " + i);
    }
}
```